# Composing CSS animations with transforms

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

I want to compose two separate CSS keyframe animations to make an image vibrate and rotate (see http://jsfiddle.net/3zAeZ/). The problem I believe I'm running into is: I'm setting the transform attribute in both keyframe rules, therefore one rule is clobbering the other.

I know this works using top & left instead of translate, but the keyframes rule will be much easier to reuse in the future if I do a transform (for example, in case I ever need to position the image differently).

I'm stumped. Can I do this? Is there a better way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple transforms like

```
transform: rotate(1337deg) scale(1.5) translate(6em, 300px);
```

Now I realize that you need two different animation durations as well.
So the best I can come up with is using two elements http://jsfiddle.net/3zAeZ/1/

Comment: Yeah, the two different timings are definitely the kink. That seems to be the only way I can think of too. Unfortunately, I can't even clean this up by using a psuedo-element since most browsers don't support animations on psudo-elements. Thanks for the answer!